# How to filter rows from Cloud Bigtable based on timestamp

Tags: java, hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using the HBase API to connect to Cloud Bigtable. I need to filter out the records which are within a particular timeframe.

The data stored in Cloud Bigtable is the following format:

```
"12345"
  a:b                       @ 2019/04/28-23:21:21.553000
    "ab"
  a:c                       @ 2019/04/28-23:21:21.553000
    "ac"
  b:d                       @ 2019/04/28-23:21:21.553000
    "bd"
```

Trying to fetch data using the Scan operation using the `setTimeRange()` method does not return me any rows. Below is the code for it:

```java
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setTimeRange(1556493680, 1556493690);
```

How can I fetch the rows based on the timestamp? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that this returns the data if you omit the setTimeRange? What you're doing should work as far as I can tell, so I wonder if something else is misconfigured.

Comment: One other possibility is that the HBase shell is printing the timestamps in your local time zone. Your unix timestamps are correct if the printed stamps are in UTC, but would be wrong if a conversion is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @DouglasMcErlean Yes, it does return the data if the setTimeRange is removed. Also, there is a continuous flow of data, thus in either time formats, there should be data present in BigTable

Comment: Is it guaranteed that any particular 10s range will contain data? What happens if you widen the range to include, say, a full day?

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed that any range of data should return a value. Also, tried running for a full day timestamp, but no records are returned

Comment: This sounds like a client bug. Can you file an issue here with details about how to reproduce? https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client/issues

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9052961/douglas-mcerlean) in the comments, the sample code provided looks correct so it's possible this is a client bug. For further diagnosis we'd recommend filing an issue in [the GitHub issue tracker for the cloud-bigtable-client project](https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client/issues).

You can also [file a support case with GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) and provide specific details about your project and Bigtable instance there.

As noted, please provide as much detail as possible about how to reproduce the issue e.g. a standalone example program that demonstrates the problem as well as the specific problematic client library version would be very helpful in further diagnosing the issue.